# Error creating bean with name Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-boot, mybatis

It's been 3rd day I've been trying to implement a simple CRUD application using Mybatis XML configuration and I'm new to the whole Spring ecosystem. The question is a bit long but I've only sharec the essentials.

I have a class `Employee.java`:

```
import lombok.*;

@Getter @Setter @AllArgsConstructor @NoArgsConstructor @ToString
public class Employee {

    private long emp_Id;
    private String emp_name;
    private String emp_dept;

}
```

Then I wrote a Mapper

```
@Mapper
public interface EmployeeMapper {

    public Employee getEmployee(@Param("emp_Id") Long emp_Id);
    public List<Employee> getAllEmployee();

}
```

Then I wrote a mapper XML named `EmployeeMapper.xml`

```
...
<mapper namespace="Employee">
    <select id="getAllEmployee" resultType="com.tmb.mybatiscrudproj.domains.Employee">
        select * from employee
    </select>

    <select id="getEmployee" resultType="com.tmb.mybatiscrudproj.domains.Employee">
        select * from employee where emp_Id = #{emp_Id}
    </select>

</mapper>
```

Then I have written a service:

```
public interface EmployeeService {

    public Employee getEmployee(Long emp_Id);
    public List<Employee> getAllEmployee();

}
```

and here is the service implementation:

```
@Service
public class EmployeeServiceImpl implements EmployeeService {

    @Autowired
    EmployeeMapper employeeMapper;

    @Override
    public List<Employee> getAllEmployee() {
        List<Employee> list = employeeMapper.getAllEmployee();
        return list;
    }

    @Override
    public Employee getEmployee(Long emp_Id) {
        return employeeMapper.getEmployee(emp_Id);
    }
}
```

and finally the controller class

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/employee")
public class EmployeeController {

    @Autowired
    EmployeeService empService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/getEmp/{empId}",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Employee getEmployee(@PathVariable Long empId){
        return empService.getEmployee(empId);
    }

    @GetMapping(value="/getAllEmp")
    public List<Employee> getAllEmployee(){
        return empService.getAllEmployee();
    }
```

I'm confused about the configurations. As I have a built-in `application.properties` inside the `resources` older and in it I have:

```
server.port: 8081

spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:~/test
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver

mybatis.config-location=classpath:mapper/mybatisConfig.xml
mybatis.mapper-locations=classpath:mapper/*Mapper.xml
mybatis.type-aliases-package=com.tmb.mybatiscrudproj.domains
mybatis.configuration.map-underscore-to-camel-case=true
mybatis.configuration.default-fetch-size=100
mybatis.configuration.default-statement-timeout=30
```

Following many tutorials and answers, I created a `mybatisConfig.xml` and `EmployeeMapper.xml` file is also inside the `resources folder.

In the `mybatisConfig.xml` I've done almost the same thing as I did in `.properties` file

```
...
<configuration>
    <environments default="development">
        <environment id="development">
            <transactionManager type="JDBC"/>
            <dataSource type="POOLED">
                <property name="driver" value="org.h2.Driver"/>
                <property name="url" value="jdbc:h2:~/test"/>
                <property name="username" value="sa"/>
                <property name="password" value=""/>
                <property name="path" value="/h2"/>
            </dataSource>
        </environment>
    </environments>
    <mappers>
        <mapper resource="EmployeeMapper.xml"/>
    </mappers>
</configuration>
```

Here is the screenshot of the project structure:

[image]

when I run the project I get the following errors:

> Error creating bean with name 'employeeController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'empService';

> nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'employeeMapper';

> nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeMapper' defined in file [MY_PATH/mybatiscrudproj/target/classes/com/tmb/mybatiscrudproj/mapper/EmployeeMapper.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through bean property 'sqlSessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [org/mybatis/spring/boot/autoconfigure/MybatisAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory]: Factory method 'sqlSessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Property 'configuration' and 'configLocation' can not specified with together

Now based on the searches I have done I made sure the in the main class I add:

```
@MappedTypes({Employee.class})
@MapperScan("com.tmb.mybatiscrudproj.mapper")
@SpringBootApplication
public class MybatiscrudprojApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MybatiscrudprojApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

but still the same error. **How can I successfully configure the project with the structure I have shared in this question**?

Comment: Remove `mybatis.config-location` and `mybatis.mapper-locations` from 'application.properties'. You don't need 'mybatisConfig.xml' and `@MapperScan` should pick up mappers. Because of the redundant configuration, MyBatis tries to load the same mapper multiple times and throws the error, probably. Read the quick setup section in the [doc](http://mybatis.org/spring-boot-starter/mybatis-spring-boot-autoconfigure/).

Answer (score 0):

Your "employeeMapper" is not declared as a spring bean, so when dependency injection, there's no bean with this type. Try adding a @Component on your class.

Answer (score 0):

add this in Mybatis-config.xml

```
<mapper>
  <package name="com.xxx.xxx.mapper">
<mapper>
```